# Removing substring from string using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question where I need to remove specific substring from string using recursion.
I was able to solve this using a do while loop but that is not the best approach.

For example,
Suppose I have a string named, DADDAUUPPA and if I am given set of substrings like "DD", "UU","PP", "AA" then the returned string should be DA because, DADDAUUPPA -> DAAUUPPA -> DUUPPA -> DPPA -> DA

Here is my solution doing it using while loop.

```
    String s = "DADDAUUPPA";
    do{
    String original = s;                                                                    
     return original.replace("DD","").replace("UU","").replace("PP","").replace("AA",""     );
    } while(!original)
```

Other challenging task is what if we are given these substrings as an array, how would we do it then?

```
For example,
    public soln (String[] sub) {
    // sub contains all the substring to be removed
    }
```

Comment: Run the code in a debugger line by line and see what it does. Or think what happens when a `return` is encountered.

Comment: There are things that recursion makes easier and faster but recursion should never be taken lightly figuring out a good recursive algorithm for good work balance between the calls and how to end the recursion while still getting what you need done is not as easy as it seems.  However when there are standard library functions that can do everything you want in one line of code using recursion does not make things easier or faster.

Comment: I would instead put the parts you need to remove from the array into another string array and iterate a for loop for the length of that array using the remove statement inside the for loop.

Comment: I get the feeling that this is a learning exercise more than a programming question. As a result, I'm not sure it is a good idea for us to solve this for you.

To write a recursive function, you need to identify:

 * The means to perform the operation in a way that can be described by the functions inputs and outputs (I know this is not that helpful, but it will make sense after you're done ;-) )
 * When the function should stop calling itself

Comment: The pseudocode for your problem might look something like:

    String removeAllRecursively(input String, substring String) {
        // updated = input without the substring
        // If nothing was removed, I guess we are done, return the input as is
        // If something was removed, call removeAllRecursively(updated, substring) and return its result
    }

Comment: given a set of substrings to be removed, there could be many possible outcomes for a final string i.e. the one that remains after all removals done, depending on the sequence of removals. For example if you have original string like "DDAD" and two substrings to be removed are DD and DA, you may have either DDAD->DD->emptystring, or DDAD->AD. So your statement "then the returned string should be DA" is wrong actually (of course unless you've tried all possible sequences)

Comment: @mangusta that is a good observation but strings would be defined in well manner where we wouldn't encounter such problems.

Comment: @DavidColer what do you mean by standard library? We can also use regular expressions for this, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> subs = new LinkedList<>();
    subs.add("DD");
    subs.add("AA");
    subs.add("UU");
    subs.add("PP");
    String result = getSubString(subs, "DADDAUUPPA ");
    System.out.print(result);
}

private static String getSubString(List<String> subs, String myString) {
   if(subs !=null && subs.size() != 0) {
       String sub = subs.get(0);
       subs.remove(0);
       myString = getSubString(subs, myString.replace(sub, ""));
   }
   return myString;
}
```

}

Key thing to learn is

```
private static String getSubString(List<String> subs, String myString) {
   if(subs !=null && subs.size() != 0) {
       myString = myString.replace(subs.get(0), "");
       subs.remove(0);
       getSubString(subs, myString);
   }
   return myString;
}
```

This does not work, note the difference between first and second `getSubString` method. As the stack unwinds `myString` gets assigned to original value.

Comment: I don't think your code will work if the string is something like "DADDADDAAUPPA" 

Since you are removing the substring everytime if you find the occurence, having multiple subs with same value would give incorrect results

Comment: for String "DADDADDAAUPPA" with sub string input {"DD", "AA", "UU", "PP"} the returned value is "DUA", isn't that what you would be expecting?

Comment: wouldn't the runtime be n^2 if we have n number of strings? @noobCoder

Comment: Runtime is number of substrings * length of original string, because the each sub string needs to be compared with all chars in the original string, thus O(n * m) if m is the length of the original string and n is the number sub strings. If m is constant then O(n). In the meanwhile can you accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: No, what I meant was, suppose we have n number of strings passed as an array which needs to be trimmed, then the run time would be n^2. 
N times to get each string from array and N times substring. making it n^2

Also, accepted the solution. Thank you so much!!!